# jQuery .next is not functioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Using the following jQuery here (in the head of the document):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function ExpCol(obj)
{
    var nextDiv = obj.next("div");
    nextDiv.animate({height: 'toggle'}, 800, function(){
        var vClass = nextDiv.is(':visible') ? 'collapse' : 'expand';
        obj.children(":first").removeClass().addClass(vClass);
    });     
}
</script>
```

HTML Markup is like so (in body):

```
<div id="reqMat" onclick="ExpCol(this);">
    <span class="expand"></span><h4 class="inlineblock">Header Text Here</h4>
</div>
<div style="display: none;">
    <p class="desc">Text in here...</p>
    <p class="desc">Text in here...</p>
</div>
```

CSS in separate stylesheet looks like this:

```
.inlineblock
{
    display: inline-block;
}
.expand, .collapse
{
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    padding-right: .1em;
    color: #605953;
}

.expand {
    content: "+";
}
.collapse
{
    content: "-";
}
```

Why is next not functioning?  Is it because I am passing `this` object into it?  If so, what is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.next()` is not available in plain DOMElements (unless you add one yourself). You are passing a DOMElement to `ExpCol()` instead of a jQuery Object.

Change

`ExpCol(this);`

to

`ExpCol($(this));`

Comment: Ahhhhhh, That's exactly it! I knew it had to do with the `this` part.  Thanks a million!  Saved me so much time!

Answer (score 2):

`this` is not a jQuery object, nor have you defined a `next` function for it. (`this` is the source of the click event, in this case the `div` DOM element itself)

I imagine you intend:

```
var nextDiv = $(obj).next("div");
```

However, since you also have a call to `obj.children`, I suggest you change your code to:

```
function ExpCol(element)
{
    var obj = $(element);

    var nextDiv = obj.next("div");
    nextDiv.animate({height: 'toggle'}, 800, function(){
        var vClass = nextDiv.is(':visible') ? 'collapse' : 'expand';
        obj.children(":first").removeClass().addClass(vClass);
    });     
}
```

or call it with `ExpCol($(this))` although this would require you to always remember to pass `ExpCol` a jQuery object.

Comment: Thanks for your input on this. techfoobar fixed it all with just 1 line.  Awesome!